# Why is 砼 considered to be dated?

Tags: usage

I saw the word 商砼 written all over a large vehicle but *Pleco Basic Chinese-English Dictionary* defines 砼 as:

> NOUN
>   DATED
>   concrete

I'm curious as to why they say 砼 is dated, I couldn't find a lot of other information about this. The character seems very much in use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the pronunciation **tóng** is dated. I think the character is normally "read" as 混凝土.

Comment: What does it mean by *dated*?

Comment: 砼 is not a universal name of concrete. 混凝土 is much more common. And, the vehicle is 混凝土車. In Hong Kong, it is called 石屎 or written as 石矢. The vehicle is as called 石屎車 or 田螺車.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is dated, I have been seeing this characters in company names as well.

The character 砼 is invented as a substitute for word 混凝土，which is often used but complicated to write. 砼 means 人工石，which is what concrete is.

You can look at [百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A0%BC) and other resources to find information on it.